# How can i count different 'ip' for same 'ads' with combining same 'adv_id' into one

Tags: sql

i have a table for finding which ip has clicked an ad but when i want to display 4 ads on my main page with first one having highest ip's count and going on.

[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBRJl.png)

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results *in the query* as text tables.  Tag with the atabase you are using.

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your title, you seem to want `count(distinct)`:

```
select adv_id, count(distinct ip)
from t
group by adv_id;
```

Comment: Gordon Linoff:do i need the visitor_counter field